# Why is my list being cleared after executing code?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm executing this code and i get `l = [[], [], []]`

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {login}')
    l = []
    f = []
    for row in c:
'''
                  row = (1000, None, 'salary', 'nevermind')
                        (1000, None, 'salary', 'nevermind')
                        (None, 2000, 'shop', 'nevermind')
'''
        for x in row:
            if x == None:
                x = 0
            f.append(x)
        l.append(f)
        f.clear()
    print(l)  # l = [[], [], []]
```

After executing this code, my list is fully empty! Why?

P.S. Sorry for making the question so ugly(

Comment: The indenting seems wrong. You can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: It would help to provide a [mre]. The database stuff seems irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your list got cleared because you cleared it:

```
    f.clear()
```

The list `l` contains nothing but references to `f`, so when you clear `f`, you're clearing all the sublists of `l`.

If you just want to build a copy of `c` with all the `None` values changed to 0, you could do something like:

```
l = [[x or 0 for x in row] for row in c]
```

Comment: So, how i can fill l from f?